# Are my personal files safe from BORA ramsomware if I have set them to 'read only'?

Tags: ransomware

A friend's PC got infected with BORA ransomware 2 days ago and I was wandering if his files would have been encrypted if he had made them 'read only' before the ransomware had struck.

Is it possible that he could have protected his data this way or is the ransomware still able to modify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ransomware hijacks your account, it can do anything you can do. This means it can just turn the read-only bit off again. Thus, this is not an effective defense.